# Copy picture to clipboard from excel -> output in program -> get smoothed picture. Where is fail?

Tags: c++, image, excel, vba, ole

Good day! If you are lazy, you can try read only **highlighted** words:)

### Source files .doc and .xls

I have the word document **colors.doc**. It's containing a **picture 325x125** with extension png and it's display 44% zoom of full size. 
I copy(**Ctrl+C**) this picture and paste(**Ctrl+V**) at **car.xls**. The picture is pasted with 44% zoom and I set it 100%. Then I **close and save** both documents.

### The program:

I have a **program**, which **open colors.doc and copy picture to clipboard** using:

> ```
>   Shapes.Item(1).Select
>   Selection.CopyAsPicture
> ```

Program **gets** it **from Clipboard** like a **EnhMetaFile** (HENHMETAFILE). And when I **play that metafile** I **get a good picture** without smoothing. Program **store** this **picture** and **close colors.doc**. Then it **open car.xls and copy picture to clipboard** using:

> Shapes.Item(1).CopyPicture(xlSreen, xlPicture) //default parameters

and my program **again gets** it like a **EnhMetaFile** (HENHMETAFILE). But when I play this **metafile** I **get smoothed picture 407x156**.

### Why it happens? How I can avoid this? Help, please I can't decide this trouble already 2 days.

### Some of my observations:

If I copy(Ctrl+C) picture from **car.xls** and paste(Ctrl+V) it to any graphical editor I get a good picture!!

### Cod:

If you are not fear WINAPI and Ole see next code please:

```
Picture::InitFromBuffer(){
    OpenClipboard(DebHDlg);
    HENHMETAFILE emfp = (HENHMETAFILE)GetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE);
    memset(&head, 0, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER));
    head.nSize = sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER);
    GetEnhMetaFileHeader(emfp, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER), &head);
    data = new BYTE[head.nBytes];
    GetEnhMetaFileBits(emfp, sizeof(BYTE)*(head.nBytes), data);
    CloseClipboard();
}

Picture::Display(HWND hDlg){
    if (hDlg != NULL){
        HDC hDC = GetDC(DebHDlg);
        int er;
        RECT r;
        HENHMETAFILE emfp = SetEnhMetaFileBits(this->head.nBytes, this->data);
        GetClientRect(DebHDlg, &r);
        if (!PlayEnhMetaFile(hDC, emfp, &r))
            er = GetLastError();
        ReleaseDC(hDlg, hDC);
        }
    }

struct Picture{
    ENHMETAHEADER head;
    BYTE *data;
    ...
};
```

I'm display it directly on main window for fast debug:)
Left picture is good. Right picture is smoothed.

[image]

Comment: Any ideas? Any queshtions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but solved it by using `Shapes.Item(1).Copy(...)` instead of `CopyPicture`.